# MVC Confirm Code sign Up Route, Dot net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have URL like http://localhost/signup?code=64525.
How I can hit Account Controller and SignUp Action?

Comment: You cannot add this to RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: i have tried using
 routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "signup-route",
                   template: "SignUp",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "SignUp" }
                );

Comment: Try changing the `template` to `url` so you will have `url: "signup"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Route("SignUp")]
        [HttpGet, AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult SignUp(string code)
        {

        return View();
    }
```

simple add this action method using this annotation, resolved my problem, no need to add any routing configuration. in dot net core 2.0